# Meaning of Matthew 21:44

Tags: matthew, jesus, parables

Matthew 21:44

> And he who falls on this stone will be broken to pieces; but on whomever it falls, it will scatter him like dust.

Jesus referred to Himself as the “stone which the builders rejected” in verse 42, so assuming that Jesus is still referring to Himself as the stone in this verse, what does it mean? What is the difference between falling on the stone and the stone falling on someone (in the context of the stone being Jesus), and what does being “broken” versus “scattered like dust” mean?

Comment: Its a reference to Dan 2: While you were watching, a rock was cut out, but not by human hands. It struck the statue on its feet of iron and clay and smashed them. 35 Then the iron, the clay, the bronze, the silver and the gold were all broken to pieces and became like chaff on a threshing floor in the summer. The wind swept them away without leaving a trace. But the rock that struck the statue became a huge mountain and filled the whole earth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This passage is the conclusion of a string of events attested to in this chapter, and so we must take these events together to understand the broader context.

### Parables about Obedience and Judgement

Just prior to this passage, the chief priests and elders had demanded a proof of Jesus' authority (Matthew 21:23-27). In response, he had asked them to judge where John's authority came from, which they declined to answer. Jesus then tells two parallel stories:

> What do you think? A man had two sons. And he went to the first and
> said, ‘Son, go and work in the vineyard today.’ And he answered, ‘I
> will not,’ but afterward he changed his mind and went.  And he went to
> the other son and said the same. And he answered, ‘I go, sir,’ but did
> not go. Which of the two did the will of his father?” They said,
> “The first.” Jesus said to them, “Truly, I say to you, the tax
> collectors and the prostitutes go into the kingdom of God before you.
> For John came to you in the way of righteousness, and you did not
> believe him, but the tax collectors and the prostitutes believed him.
> And even when you saw it, you did not afterward change your minds and
> believe him. (Matthew 21:28-31)

In the first, there are two sons - one, like the 'sinners' of their day, who at first decline to obey the father but then are obedient, and the second, like the religious leaders, who claim to be obedient but do not obey. And he presses the point that their unwillingness to acknowledge John's authority attests to this.

---

> Hear another parable. There was a master of a house who planted a
> vineyard, put a fence around it and dug a winepress in it and
> built a tower and leased it to tenants, and went into another
> country. When the season for fruit drew near, he sent his servants
> to the tenants to get his fruit. And the tenants took his
> servants and beat one, killed another, and stoned another. Again
> he sent other servants, more than the first. And they did the same to
> them. Finally he sent his son to them, saying, ‘They will respect
> my son.’ But when the tenants saw the son, they said to themselves,
> ‘This is the heir. Come, let us kill him and have his inheritance.’
> And they took him and threw him out of the vineyard and killed
> him. When therefore the owner of the vineyard comes, what will he
> do to those tenants?” They said to him, “He will put those
> wretches to a miserable death and let out the vineyard to other
> tenants who will give him the fruits in their seasons.” (Matthew 21:32-41)

In the second, Jesus builds on his first parable - this time the obedience is requested by a master to his servants, and they not only disobey but begin to steal and commit violence against the master. And at last, they kill the master's own son.

---

### The Twist: From Joy to Judgement

At this point Jesus draws on scripture:

> Jesus said to them, “Have you never read in the Scriptures:
>
> ‘**The stone that the builders rejected has become the cornerstone**; this
> was the Lord’s doing, and it is marvelous in our eyes’? [Psalm 118:22-23]
>
> Therefore I tell you, the kingdom of God will be taken away from you
> and given to a people producing its fruits. **And the one who falls on
> this stone will be broken to pieces; and when it falls on anyone, it
> will crush him**.”
>
> When the chief priests and the Pharisees heard his parables, they
> perceived that he was speaking about them. And although they were
> seeking to arrest him, they feared the crowds, because they held him
> to be a prophet. (Matthew 21:42-46)

Jesus draws on the fresh and exuberant joy the people have already been thinking about from Psalm 118 - the Lord requesting entry into Jerusalem, the people bringing him in, and actually the same Psalm the people had been singing when Jesus had entered the city the day before *(v25 - Hosanna, v26 - Blessed is he who comes in the name of the Lord)*. And Jesus suddenly binds together the celebrations with a recognition of the prophecy about the cornerstone.

Jesus' point is that he is *both* the entering Lord/King and the cornerstone which would be rejected. Their rejection of Jesus and John is as much a fulfilment of prophecy as his triumphal entry was the day before, and prophesied in the very same passage. And Jesus' application of being the cornerstone was that therefore it was foolish to oppose him - at best, they can hope to fall over him and be broken, but if he falls on them, they will be crushed to dust.

---

### Application

Jesus is really talking about the directionality of conflict with God - we can oppose God, just as the religious leaders opposed Jesus, and in that case they can expect to continually stumble and be broken by such conflict. But it's not an 'even' conflict - if the day ever comes for God to oppose us, we will be crushed.

For the Chief Priests and Elders, they will in the days to come make many decisions that oppose God, which will bring their own downfall. For Joseph of Arimathea and whichever leaders would go on to repent at Pentecost or thereafter, they would be broken, but restored and made whole through Jesus. Like the son who was later obedient, they will do the will of the Father. However, for those who would continue to reject them, the ultimate outcome would be that of the second parable - "He will put those wretches to a miserable death and let out the vineyard to other tenants who will give him the fruits in their seasons." (v41)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, Steve! This was incredibly thorough and helpful; I had never thought about this passage in the way you described (it not being an "even" conflict), but it makes so much sense. Thank you for taking the time to write this answer!

Comment: You're welcome Gremosa, this was a very enlightening passage to exegete - I preached on the Triumphal Entry for a local church last year and how Psalm 118 was being sung as Jesus entered, and so how delighted was I to realise Jesus specifically quoted from the Psalm like this before the chapter even ended. Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

"Whether the stone hits the jug, or the jug hits the stone, it is the jug that breaks."  We, by complicity with sin fall against the Truth of Christ and are broken.  Nothing is more certain than that Christ will crush Sin.  He will crush Sin to powder.  Yet our Lord, forgiving the penitent, lifts the Faithful by Grace from their involvement in this doom.

Answer (score 0):

[Psalms תהילים 118:22] "The stone that the builders rejected became a "corner" (Pinnah, פִּנָּֽה) "stone" (Even, אֶבֶן). * Read the Hebrew :  "( אֶבֶן מָֽאֲס֣וּ הַבּוֹנִ֑ים הָֽ֜יְתָ֗ה לְרֹ֣אשׁ פִּנָּֽה ) - referencing a literal stone tablet (Covenant of God, בְּרִית אֱלֹהִים) rejected by the sons of Yisrael.

David's son שלמה Shlomoh in Proverbs 10:25 explains that the צַדִּיק "righteous" person maintains the world's foundation, while King David believed the אֶבֶן Even "stone" containing מִּצְו‍ֹתֶיךָ Mitsvoteikha "Your-Commandments" [Psalm 119] kept the righteous alive.

The rejected cornerstone of God remains δὸς τοῖς πτωχοῖς (Mark 10:21), as King David's son שלמה Shlomoh stated צְדָקָה תַּצִּיל מִמָּוֶת Tsedakah saves from death (Proverbs 10:2).

Answer (score 0):

> Matthew 21:44
> Anyone who falls on this stone will be broken to pieces [συνθλασθήσεται]; anyone on whom it falls will be crushed [λικμήσει]."

> Luke 20:18
> Everyone who falls on that stone will be broken to pieces [συνθλασθήσεται]; anyone on whom it falls will be crushed [λικμήσει]."

These are the only times these two Greek words appear in the Bible. I don't think Jesus was making an important distinction here.

> Matthew 21:45 When the **chief priests and the Pharisees** heard Jesus' parables, they knew he was talking about **them**.

> Luke 20:19 The **teachers of the law and the chief priests** looked for a way to arrest him immediately, because they knew he had spoken this parable against **them**.

Note the switching order: chief priests first in Matthew and second in Luke. Again, the order is not important. The pairs are meant to show parallelism. What is important is this: Whoever you are, chief priests and whatnot, if you trip on Jesus' word or against His word, you will not be whole.